# Does paypal provide offline token or master token?

Tags: paypal

I have create an application in paypal sandbox account. I want to do when some of the user click 'transfer money' button, then paypal transfer money from my account to user's account (Note: we have user's email id).

So, it possible to transfer money without authentication to paypal account something like offline access method.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a [billing agreement](https://www.paypal.com/gb/webapps/helpcenter/helphub/article/?solutionId=FAQ1848&topicID=&m=ARA), where the user authorizes you to make payments against a PayPal account in the same way you would debit a bank account or credit card. Billing agreements are typically set up in the same way Express Checkout works, but you will be provided an ID to refer to when you need to make payments.

> A Billing Agreement allows a seller to charge your PayPal account when you purchase goods from them or use their service.
>
> An example of this would be an agreement to pay eBay seller fees for listing items on eBay.